# How can I see what documents have been deleted from a Document Library?

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-online, delete, auditing

I have a document library that had files in it yesterday. Today it does not. When trying to view some sort of an audit log I realized I didn't know how to. I'm using SharePoint 2013 Online.

How can I view what users have modified a document library and especially see who has deleted a document in one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing, you make sure you are recording the Deletion in your audit log. you can check here [Configure audit settings for a site collection](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-HA102866204.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA102772739)

**Now following events available for audit log reports**
The following events are available for audit log reports to help you determine who is taking what actions with the content of a site collection:

- Opened and downloaded documents, viewed items in lists, or viewed
  item properties (This event is not available for SharePoint Online
  sites)
- Edited items
- Checked out and checked in items
- Items that have been moved and copied to other location in the site
  collection
- Deleted and restored items
- Changes to content types and columns
- Search queries
- Changes to user accounts and permissions
- Changed audit settings and deleted audit log events
- Workflow events
- Custom events

**View Log Reports:** As you asked how can you view it.

To view an audit log report:

On the Settings menu, click Site settings.
 NOTE    The Site Collection Administration section will not be available if you do not have the necessary permissions, such as by being a member of the default Site Collections Administrators group.

- In the Site Collection Administration section, select Audit log
  reports.
- On the View Auditing Reports page, select the report that you want,
  such as Deletion.
- Type or Browse to the library where you want to save the report and
  click OK.
- On the Operation Completed Successfully page, click click here to
  view this report.

Deletion reports looks like this

[image]

check this for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the specific document library, you could look in the recycle bin for that site, or even the site collection recycle bin.

PS:http://askpt.co.uk/2012/11/22/sharepoint-2013-what-and-where-is-the-recycle-bin/

Comment: http://askpt.co.uk/2012/11/22/sharepoint-2013-what-and-where-is-the-recycle-bin/